# Pebble full screen slides

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I want to use the **Panel dots UI pattern** in my Pebble app, which is mentioned [here](http://assets.getpebble.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev-portal/UX-Design-Guide-v1.1.pdf).

How can I use it?
I can not find anything about it inside the developer documentation.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no built in UI element for implementing this pattern, it is something you would have to build yourself.
2. That design guide is now obsolete. You should check out our new design guides at https://developer.getpebble.com/guides/design-and-interaction/ for the up-to-date guidelines.